# OleDataAdapter Fill Method Returning Empty Rows To Data Table

Tags: c#, excel, oledbcommand

Here is my code:

```
public static DataTable GetDataFromSpreadsheet(OleDbConnection conn)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", conn);
        conn.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        conn.Close();
        return dt;
    }
```

When this method is called, I don't get an error at all! When I put a watch on the data table (dt), I can see that it is empty. No row headers, and the rows are empty. I know the query is valid to some degree, because the Rows.Count on dt returns the number of rows in the sheet that I am querying.

What could I be doing incorrectly?

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT: Here is my Connection String**

```
<add name="EXCEL" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
           Data Source={0};
           Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;
           HDR=Yes; IMEX=1;'" />
```

I am putting the file location in place of {0}

Comment: How can you get Rows.count over dt when your datatable is empty ?

Comment: I step through the code in VS2013. When I get to the Da.fill(dt), I look at the dt variable, and the row count shows the row count. However, if I look at the content of the rows, they are empty.

Comment: put a break point on da.fill(dt); and check you dt after executing this line ? check your query also on your database may be you have no rows on your database?

Comment: This isnt a database, I am querying an excel sheet. the line of code executes just fine. After it executes, then I look at the data table variable, and that is when I notice my problem.

Comment: The column count (47) is the same as it is in the excel sheet as well.

Comment: have you specify Header (HDR="YES")  in your connection string ? Edit your question and add connection string

Comment: Does your data contains integers only? Show us the connection string.

Comment: Mostly text, and i updated with conn string.

Comment: conn string is read from app.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Establish a Connection**

```
String strExcelConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
+ "Data Source=Book1.xls;"
+ "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes'";

OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(strExcelConn);
OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;
```

**Accessing Sheets**

```
connExcel.Open();
DataTable dtExcelSchema;
dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
connExcel.Close(); 
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";
da.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
da.Fill(ds);
connExcel.Close();
```

- [**REFERENCE**](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Read-Excel-file-using-OLEDB-Data-Provider-in-C-Net.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link

https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Try setting `IMEX=1` or `HDR=YES` in your connection string

Comment: I cannot see IMEX=1 in your connection string

Comment: It is there now, tested in program and still having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

DataAdapter.Fill Method overload list is following:

- Fill(DataSet)
- Fill(DataTable, IDataReader)
- Fill(DataTable[], IDataReader, Int32, Int32)
- Fill(DataSet, String, IDataReader, Int32, Int32)

There is no method with single DataTable parameter.

In your case you can use Fill(DataSet) method and return .Tables[0] or .Tables["TableName"];

Have a look following code:

```
public static DataTable GetDataFromSpreadsheet(OleDbConnection conn)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", conn);
    conn.Open();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
    conn.Close();
    return ds.Tables[0];
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and I am still getting an empty table.

Comment: You are wrong. There is a overload that admits DataTable only.